# Rubber margins in chapters

Tags: spacing, margins

I couldn't find a Google hit with what I need (try: `LaTeX rubber margins`). So, is it possible to stretch left/right margins, within defined acceptable limits, so that pages are filled optimally? I'm using pdfLaTeX.

E.g., chapter of 3 pages, last one has only a few lines: Means expanding margins of that chapter so text is in 2 pages.

I would like to keep page margins within chapters identical, only allowing differences between chapters. An option to exclude certain chapters is also desireable.

Shrinking margins to maximize filling will not be needed, the goal is to eliminate pages with alot of blank space, typically at the end of a chapter.

And by possible I mean doable by a novice without needing to code for days.
Maybe there are better options? I am also using the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package.

Comment: That's pretty hard to do in TeX. There is very little linkage between the line and page breaking. It is of course easy to manually change the margins at the chapter breaks, or (more directly) use `\enlargethispage` to allow some pages to be a line longer to avoid running over at the end, but doing it automatically is probably not feasible while maintaining compatibility with common packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll make this comment an answer since no one suggested anything else.

That's pretty hard to do in TeX. There is very little linkage between the line and page breaking. It is of course easy to manually change the margins at the chapter breaks, or (more directly) use `\enlargethispage` to allow some pages to be a line longer to avoid running over at the end, but doing it automatically is probably not feasible while maintaining compatibility with common packages.